# Spatial derivatives and weak convergence in Bochner spaces

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, bochner-spaces

Consider $V=H^1(\Omega)$ and a bounded sequence $f_n$ in $B = L^2((0,1),V)$, which is Hilbert with $(f,g)_B = \int_0^1(f,g)+(\nabla f, \nabla g)$.

Then, there exists $f \in B$ with, for all $g \in B$, the convergence $\int_0^1(f_n,g)+(\nabla f_n, \nabla g)\rightarrow \int_0^1(f,g)+(\nabla f, \nabla g)$.

> Can we conclude that $\int_0^1(f_n,g)\rightarrow \int_0^1(f,g)$  and $\int_0^1 (\partial_i f_n, g)\rightarrow \int_0^1(\partial_i  f, g)$, for all $g \in L^2(I,H)$?

This seems a very natural property for me to hold, but I couldn't get to prove it.

One could I guess try the weak convergence  $(f_n,g)+(\nabla f_n, \nabla g)\rightarrow (f,g)+(\nabla f, \nabla g)$ for almost every time, but I think this is not attainable. On the other hand, a density argument where $p$ is substituted by functions with compact supports in space, doesn't seem to lead anywhere, as one cannot recover $B$ by such functions... Any idea here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that $H = L^2(\Omega)$ and $I = (0,1)$.

For every $g \in L^2(I;H)$, the mappings
\begin{align*}
V \in f &\mapsto \int_I (f,g)_H \, \mathrm{d}t,\\
V \in f &\mapsto \int_I (\partial f_i,g)_H \, \mathrm{d}t
\end{align*}
are linear and continuous from $V$ to $\mathbb R$.
Since $f_n$ converges weakly in $V$ towards $f$,
your desired convergences follow.